# Centering image in power bi tooltip

Tags: powerbi

I have Image Url and it appears they might be different sizes.
So I get [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JtRt.png)
[image]

[image]

ANY way to fix this alignment in Power BI?